# How to design the infrastructure for an application serving USA and Canada?

Tags: infrastructure, network-design

I am developing a service that will be applicable for both Americans and Canadians, the data collected and stored are not legally allowed to cross the borders...which is new to my knowledge.

So what is the best practice to serve both countries?

We already have two servers, one in each country. What I am doing now is replicate the whole system on both servers, each server has his own domain name. When I need to update the code I will have to do it on both, I think there is a better way, No?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're legally enjoined from sending the data across the borders you're pretty much stuck with the solution you described: Two environments running the same code in two different countries.

Be thankful the sites are identical (they are, aren't they?) - Invest (time and/or money) in a decent remote deployment solution and you'll only have to develop, test & debug once, then deploy to both sites.

Comment: Sounds like an ideal solution for Puppet.

Comment: Puppet, radmind, any of that type of software is ideal for this.

Answer (score 1):

Our company had the same type of problem. The solution that we did is have the database servers and reporting servers in each country and the applications servers are in Canada.  I would suspect the problem that you have with cross border data is the Patriot Act, specially on the Canadian side.

Answer (score 0):

Might be better to speak to a specialist lawyer but if you're not allowed to 'cross the border' with the data and you're effectively doing this now with the replication I could only recommend you to stop now.

Basically you're going to have to shard your database, it's that simple.

Comment: I am not crossing the border with the data, What I am doing now is a totally separating two environment for each country. Each one with its own database and application server.